# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS 302 with ELK Operator 7.10.0 using Server.basePath

Tags: kubernetes, kibana, elastic-stack, istio

I have an Elastic stack with `elasticsearch` and `kibana` version `7.10.0` using `elk` operator in kubernetes

Whenever I enter the link https://monitoring.cloudapp.azure.com/kibana I'm getting this redirection:

```
https://monitoring.cloudapp.azure.com/kibana/login?next=%2Fkibana%2Fkibana%2Flogin%3Fnext%3D%2Fkibana%2Fkibana%2Flogin%3Fnext%3D%252Fkibana%252Fkibana%
```

In the `Pod` logs:

```
"type":"response","@timestamp":"2020-12-23T15:38:27Z","tags":,"pid":7,"method":"get","statusCode":302,"req":{"url":"/kibana/login?next=%2Fkibana%2Fkibana%2Flogin%3Fnext%3D%252Fkibana%252.....
```

`Kibana.yaml`

```
apiVersion: kibana.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Kibana
metadata:
  name: kibana
spec:
  version: 7.10.0
  count: 1
  elasticsearchRef:
    name: elastic-https
  http:
    service:
      spec:
        type: ClusterIP
    tls:
      selfSignedCertificate:
        disabled: true
  podTemplate:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kibana
        env:
        - name: SERVER_BASEPATH
          value: "/kibana"
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 4Gi
            cpu: 1
          limits:
            memory: 8Gi
            cpu: 2
    metadata:
      annotations:
        sidecar.istio.io/rewriteAppHTTPProbers: "true"
```

`kibana.ingress.yaml`

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: istio
  name: kibana-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - host: "monitoring.cloudapp.azure.com"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /kibana/login.*
            backend:
              serviceName: kibana-kb-http
              servicePort: 5601
          - path: /kibana
            backend:
              serviceName: kibana-kb-http
              servicePort: 5601
          - path: /kibana/*
            backend:
              serviceName: kibana-kb-http
              servicePort: 5601
```

No way with incognito window, I have the same problem whenever I do a `kubectl port-forward` I stumble upon the same problem with the redirection (with `HTTP`)

```
> http://localhost:52000/kibana/login?next=%2Fkibana%2Fkibana%2Flogin%3Fnext%
```

Comment: Hello. Did I understand you correctly that whenever you are trying to access Kibana dashboard with `$ kubectl port-forward` you are getting `too many redirects message`? Have you tried to delete `SERVER_BASEPATH`? Does it work then?

Comment: yes with  port-forward i have the same probleme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to add server.rewriteBasePath: true  like this

```
---
apiVersion: kibana.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Kibana
metadata:
  name: kibana
spec:
  config:
    server.rewriteBasePath: true
```

and update the readinessProbe like :

```
 podTemplate:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kibana
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            scheme: HTTP
            path: /kibana
            port: 5601
        env:
        - name: SERVER_BASEPATH
          value: "/kibana"
```

don't forget with more than 1 replica set the redirect from / kibana to /kibana/login doesn't works

Comment: thanks! After updating the server.rewriteBasePath: true (default in v6 false, in v7 deprecated, in v8 true ) is working like a charm!